How to aggregate in Spark SQL
I have a dataset like
user_id  |  value
1111        NULL
1111        active
2222        active  

I want to group by and get the first available value for each user so I do
select 
    user_id,
    COLLECT_LIST(value) [0]
from table; 

which doesn't work as for 11111 the value NULL is shown.
I try
select 
    user_id,
    COALESCE(value)
from table; 

But that returns an array not a string. Is there a function in spark SQL which can help me with this

SELECT 
    user_id,
    first(value, true) AS first_value
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    user_id;

The first(value, true) function takes two parameters: the column to analyze (value) and a boolean indicating whether to ignore null values (true). This should work as intended, returning the first available non-null entry for each user. If all entries for a user are null, it returns null.

You can try filtering out null values first:
select 
    user_id,
    COLLECT_LIST(value) [0]
from table
where value IS NOT NULL;

